# Unable to import modules from aws lambda layer

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a requirements file for my pip packages. I installed it in a target folder and zipped the contents and uploaded it on AWS lambda layer.

Requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.2.3
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
cloudevents==0.2.4
decorator==4.4.1
Django==3.0
idna==2.8
jaeger-client==4.2.0
jsonpath-ng==1.4.3
pbr==5.4.4
ply==3.11
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
six==1.13.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
urllib3==1.25.7
aws-xray-sdk
mysql-connector-python
gunicorn
```

I used the command `pip3 install -r requirements.txt -t python/` where python is the target directory. This image shows the content of python directory.
[image]

After this I zipped the content of this directory and published it as a layer on aws lambda. I made a dummy lambda function to check if the layer is working or not.

```
import json
import django

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

The log file error :

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
}

Request ID:
"66ce85e0-59f0-4e5c-98f9-6fa3e3eb17d0"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 66ce85e0-59f0-4e5c-98f9-6fa3e3eb17d0 Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'django'

END RequestId: 66ce85e0-59f0-4e5c-98f9-6fa3e3eb17d0
REPORT RequestId: 66ce85e0-59f0-4e5c-98f9-6fa3e3eb17d0  Duration: 0.64 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 42 MB  Init Duration: 1.81 ms
```

Comment: have you mapped lambda layer to lambda ?

Comment: Are you sure  you run it with the same python as the pip you are using to install the packages?

Comment: as said by Reznik both has to same python version.

Comment: @aviboy2006 yeah, I added the layer to the above lambda function. Is that what you mean by mapping?

Comment: @Reznik If I run pip3 --version on my terminal I get
pip 20.1.1 from  ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

and the runtime for my lambda function is also python 3.6

Comment: consider run `python -m pip install requirement.txt` and then try it, maybe you have like a venv or something like that that messing things up

Comment: You can use serverless. It is easy to use and easy to deploy your local code as a lambda function. https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: Also, please edit your question to show the _exact_ `pip` command that you're using, and a listing of the project directory after you run it.

Comment: @Parsifal edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If layer would suite you, I can let you know that I just **successful constructed a django layer** based on your `requirements.txt` file which could be imported in lambda.

To build the layer I used [lambci/lambda](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda) tool. To ease the process, I used the following snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695187/import-libraries-in-lambda-layers/55696651#55696651).

The layer had 42 MB which is close to the 50 MB limit of lambda.

If you don't want to use layer, you can also use the same docker tool to **build regular deployment packag**e as explained in the recent AWS blog:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

Since layer works, including django in a regular package should also work.

Comment: I have done exactly the same thing given in that snippet. Do we have to give some specific permission in order to use a layer?

Comment: @Adishukla no special permissions required.

Comment: It's running now thanks! Could you take a look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62427304/calling-a-django-function-view-from-an-aws-lambda-function

Comment: @Cool. Can you accept the questions if you find them useful?

Comment: @Adishukla Thanks. I checked the new question, but unfortunately its beyond my djnago knowledge :-(

Answer (score 5):

You mention that you 'zipped the content of this directory' referring to the python folder. When you create a layer via a .zip package, python packages need to be in a 'python' folder subdirectory. They can not be all at the root of the zipped folder.

Comment: bro you're a true hero

Answer (score 3):

Asked and answered, but if anybody else runs into this thread who is trying to bake their own Python layer, here's how I got set things up to work...

Directory structure for the .zip you submit as the Lambda layer (thanks Ryan Lutz for the reminder about the "python" directory):

```
python/
   fubar /
      __init.py__
      foo.py
```

**__init.py__**

```
from .foo import Foo
```

**foo.py**

```
class Foo:
   def bar(self):
      print("Fubar!")
```

In your Lambda function (with the layer added)...

```
from fubar import Foo

var foo = Foo()
print (foo.bar())
```