# Calling a django function view from an aws lambda function

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I want to run my django views on AWS Lambda. For this I had created a lambda function which is calling that view function. The AWS lambda function is something like this ->

```
import app.views as v

def functionA_handler(event, context): 

    some_value = v.functionA(event)
    return some_value
```

The corresponding view in app.views file would be something like this ->

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
@csrf_exempt
def functionA(request):
  request_body = json.loads(request.body)
  return JsonResponse(request_body, status=200)
```

How can I link the above lambda function to the view function? The view takes an input of the form request which is creating an issue here. Any solution?

Comment: Consider using [zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) to deploy Django or Flask apps into AWS Lambda.

Comment: @jarmod yeah I know about zappa, but is there some other way to do this?